# 5.5.1 authentication error required in c#

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, email

I have tried most of the tweaks advised but none work.

I have tried :

1.Enabling 2-step verification on gmail 

2.Enabled less secured app on gmail

3.Changed password to strong

Earlier I made an account for in gmail and by mistake entered a wrong phone number.But that email workjed fine on my C# application, I was able to send email. But, as I am India and client in US, so had put location as US. So when logged into gmail it logged me out saying *some suspicious activity* So I had to create a new account.
But since then it gave me an error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

heres my code :

```
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(txtsmtp.Text);

c ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { 
                return true; 
            };


    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Port = Convert.ToInt16(txtport.Text);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtuserid.Text, txtpassword.Text);

       client.EnableSsl = true;

        client.Timeout = 200000;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(txtsendto.Text);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(cmbuseremailaddress.Text);
        mail.Subject = txtsubject.Text;
        mail.Body = txtmessage.Text;
        mail.Bcc.Add(textBox1.Text);
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;



        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent Successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

Here port no I am using is 587

So please let me know where and what I am missing.

Thanks